# Vue js add History pushstate by checkbox checked

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, pushstate, html5-history

I've a list of checkbox and I want create a history push state (?transmission[]=manual&transmission[]=automatic). I need this for sharing link. Any ideas?
Thanks!